# Как сохранить созданный файл Word без появления диалогового окна?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-interop, interop

```
using System;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Создаём новый Word.Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Загружаем документ
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;

        object fileName = "E:\\Word.docx";
        object falseValue = false;
        object trueValue = true;
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref trueValue,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        //Теперь у нас есть документ который мы будем менять.

        //Очищаем параметры поиска
        app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
        app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

        //Задаём параметры замены и выполняем замену.
        object findText = "<Name>";
        object replaceWith = "<На что меняем>";
        object replace = 2;

        app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceWith,
        ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);



        //Открываем документ для просмотра.
        app.Visible = true;
       // doc.SaveAs("E:\\News.docx");
        //app.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        //doc.SaveAs("E:\\News.docx");

        string path1 = "E:\\News.docx";
        app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(FileName: path1);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Автор, ты ведь уже написал, но по какой-то причине закомментировал отключение алертов.

```
app.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

Опять же, учти, что сохранение документа под другим именем не отменяет того факта, что с текущим нужно что-то сделать. Например, закрыть без сохранения изменений, в противном случае ты всё равно получишь вопрос при закрытии приложения.

Comment: Не выполняется строка